# Switch from f to F in Vim without ,

Tags: vim

After using the `f{char}` motion, is it possible to change directions so `;` will go backwards (as if you used `F{char}`)? (And vice-versa and with `tT`.)

I'm going to try using `,` as LocalLeader and I have this to let me access `,` again:

```
let maplocalleader = ','
nnoremap <LocalLeader><LocalLeader> <LocalLeader>
```

But I wonder if I can map `<LocalLeader>;` to make `;` switch between acting like `;` and `,`. I don't see anywhere the character for `f` is stored, so can I do this?

Comment: Did anyone else read the title of this question and think "Use Shift or Caps Lock!"?

Comment: Do you want `,;` to act like `,`? Using `,` as `leader` or `localleader` only introduces a delay in which Vim is waiting for further key presses. After the delay passes, 1 second if you didn't change the default value, `,` acts normally: it does the previous motion in the opposite direction.

Comment: Why not just use `,`?  That does exactly what you are asking (from what I can tell).  It searches in the reverse direction for the same character.

Comment: @JordanParmer: If I remap `,` (to be localleader), then I'll have to wait `timeoutlen` for Vim to recognize that I wanted `,` instead of a command starting with localleader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this cannot be done, unless you re-implement the `f` command yourself (which isn't so difficult as it sounds; there are actually plugins that enhance it to search in subsequent lines, too). It can be done for `n` / `N` (via `v:searchforward`), though.

In general, I would advise from employing such clever "tricks"; they retrain your muscle memory, and cause problems in other environments with vi-like keybindings (Pentadactyl, Bash, readline, some IDEs). Rather, rethink your approach to mappings.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you map Leader and LocalLeader to?

Comment: @pydave: I keep them both at the default (backslash); it's convenient for me with a US-English keyboard. Additionally, I have some custom movements and text objects starting with `,` (especially my camelcasemotion plugin).